# PySpark - Timestamp behavior

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to understand behaviour differences between ***pyspark.sql.currenttimestamp()*** and ***datetime.now()***

If I create a Spark dataframe in DataBricks using these 2 mechanisms to create a timestamp column, everything works nicely as expected....

```
curDate2 = spark.range(10)\
  .withColumn("current_date_lit",F.lit(date.today()))\
  .withColumn("current_timestamp_lit",F.lit(F.current_timestamp()))\
  .withColumn("current_timestamp",F.current_timestamp())\
  .withColumn("now",F.lit(datetime.now()))

+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|current_date_lit|current_timestamp_lit|   current_timestamp|                 now|
+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
|  1|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
|  2|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

However, when I then call show() on the dataframe a couple of minutes later the columns based on *currenttimestamp()* show me the time NOW (16:44) whilst the *datetime.now()* column shows me the timestamp from the first creation of the dataframe (16:40)

Clearly one column holds a literal value & the other enumerates the function at runtime but I'm at a loss to understand why they behave differently

show() a few mins later...

```
+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|current_date_lit|current_timestamp_lit|   current_timestamp|                 now|
+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
|  1|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
|  2|      2022-02-12| 2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:44:...|2022-02-12 16:40:...|
+---+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Thanks - I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Good question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question that I tried out with `rand()` function just to check. It is sort of intuitive, but at the same time an Action without some prior `.cache()` applied to some data, would lead one to believe, a new round --> a new set of results.

- `show()` is an Action with some smarts. Here is is based on the same underlying rdd and logically one would expect a deterministic outcome - at least I think so.
- However, `F.current_timestamp()` is evaluated once at serialization time. So, two successive `show()`'s will have 2 different times. The other answer states that and points to the docs. So that is an exception and thus  tried with `rand()`. See below.
- `Datetime.now()` is held constant by Spark - see WholeStageCodeGen - just how it works as it concerns the same underlying DF; it assumes the first lit function still applies because the preceding creation of the DF (underlying RDD) still exists. I did a check with `rand()` and all successive `show()` Actions return the same sequence of random numbers - the same seed is used. This emulates *deterministic* behaviour which is what we would want with 2 successive `show()` 's
- With a new DF with same name, then that is also re-evaluated, obviously.

You can try and see what happens if you use .cache().

It is a contrived example `range(10)` of course.

Answer (score 1):

1. `current_timestamp()` returns a TimestampType column, the value of which is evaluated at query time as described in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp.html). So that is 'computed'  each time your call `show`.

> Returns the current timestamp at the start of query evaluation as a
> TimestampType column. All calls of current_timestamp within the same
> query return the same value.

2. Passing this column to a `lit` call doesn't change anything, if you check the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#lit) you can see `lit` simply returns the column you called it with.

> return col if isinstance(col, Column) else _invoke_function("lit",
> col)

3. If you cal `lit` with something else than a column, e.g. a datetime object then a new column is created with this literal value. The literal being the datetime object returned from datetime.now(). This is a static value representing the time the datetime.now function was called.

Comment: Not sure the answer makes sense, last text.

Comment: You mean called lit function first.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I should have removed the F.lit. A failed attempt to get static behaviour... I still don't understand why datetime.now() acts differently?

Comment: val vs. def, i will look tomorrow.

Comment: I've tried to clarify further, if still unclear better wait on thebluephantom :)

Comment: More observation  than answer. Rand also shows same effect.

Comment: point 3 is not good enough.